# Memory Alignment warning with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, memory-alignment, strict-aliasing, intrusive-containers

I'm trying to implement a polymorphic data structure e.g. an intrusive linked list (I already know the kernel has one - this is more of learning experience).

The trouble is casting a nested struct to the containing struct leads to `gcc` issuing a memory-alignment warning.

The specifics are provided below:

```
// t.c
#include <stdio.h>

enum OL_TYPE { A, B, C };

struct base {
    enum OL_TYPE type;
};

struct overlay {
    struct base base;
    int i;
};

struct overlay2 {
    struct base base;
    float f;
    int i;
    // double d;     // --> adding this causes a memory alignment warning
};

void testf(struct base *base) {
     if (base->type == A) {
        struct overlay *olptr = (struct overlay *)base;
        printf("overlay->i = %d\n", olptr->i);
    } else
    if (base->type == B) {
        struct overlay2 *olptr = (struct overlay2 *)base;
        printf("overlay->i = %d\n", olptr->i);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct overlay ol;
    ol.base.type = A;
    ol.i = 3;

    testf(&ol.base);
}
```

Compiled with `gcc t.c -std=c99 -pedantic -fstrict-aliasing -Wcast-align=strict -O3 -o q` leads to this:

```
t.c: In function ‘testf’:
t.c:28:34: warning: cast increases required alignment of target type [-Wcast-align]
   28 |         struct overlay2 *olptr = (struct overlay2 *)base;
      |                                  ^
```

It's interesting to notice that if I comment out the `double` from `overlay2` such that it's not part of the structure anymore, the warning disappears.

In light of this, I have a few questions:

1. Is there any danger to this?
2. If yes, what is the danger? If not, does that mean the warning is a false positive and how can it be dealt with?
3. Why does adding the double suddenly lead to the alignment warning?
4. Is misalignment / an alignment problem even possible if I cast from base to a `struct overlay2 *` **IF** the actual type IS in fact a `struct overlay2` with a nested `struct base` ? Please explain!

Appreciate any answers that can provide some insight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. is there any danger to this?

Only if what `base` points to was not allocated as a `struct overlay2` in the first place. If you're just smuggling in a pointer to `struct overlay2` as a `struct base*`, and casting back internally, that should be fine (the address would actually be aligned correctly in the first place).

> 2. If yes, what is the danger? If not, does that mean the warning is a false positive and how can it be dealt with?

The danger occurs when you allocate something as something other than `struct overlay2` then try to use the unaligned `double` inside it. For example, a union of `struct base` and `char data[sizeof(struct overlay2)]` would be the right size to contain a `struct overlay2`, but it might be four byte aligned but not eight byte aligned, causing the `double` (size 8, alignment 8) to be misaligned. On x86 systems, a misaligned field typically just slows your code, but on non-x86 misaligned field access can crash your program.

As for dealing with it, you can silence the warning (with some compiler-specific directives), or you can just force all your structures to be aligned identically, by adding `alignas` directives (available since C11/C++11):

```
#include <stdalign.h> // Add at top of file to get alignas macro

struct base {
    alignas(double) enum OL_TYPE type;
};
```

> 3. why does adding the double suddenly lead to the alignment warning?

Because it's the only data type in any of the structures that requires eight byte alignment; without it, the structures can all be legally aligned to four bytes; with it, `overlay2` needs eight byte alignment while the others only need four byte alignment.

> 4. is an alignment even possible if I cast from base to a struct overlay2 * IF the actual type IS in fact a struct overlay2 with a nested struct base ?

As noted above, if it was really pointing to something allocated as a `struct overlay2` all along, you're safe.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a false positive, because the compiler doesn't *know* that your passed `base*` argument will be the address of an actual `overlay2` structure (even though you do). However, if that condition is always going to be true, then no issue should arise due to inappropriate alignment.

However, to be completely sure (and to silence the warning), you could always make the `base` structure align to the requirements of a `double`, if that doesn't cause any other issues:

```c
struct base {
    _Alignas(double) enum OL_TYPE type;
};
```

> *Why does adding the double suddenly lead to the alignment warning*

Because, in general, the alignment requirement of any structure must be at least that of the largest alignment requirement of all its members. Without such an assurance, an array of those structures would – by definition – result in misalignment of such members in any one one of two adjacent elements in the array.

Comment: thank you! The `alignas` macro seems to indeed do the trick here. However, is it a concern at all the space that this would take up in padding? I.e. if the `base` struct only contained a `char` for example (1 byte) and I aligned it to e.g. `long double` (16 bytes on my machine) to satisfy a compiler warning such as the one in this case. Or am I misunderstanding what `alignas` would do here?

Comment: @Daniel First, `_Alignas` is a *keyword*, not a macro. On the issue of extra space ... I'll need to check up the specs, but, IIRC, there are some circumstances where padding bytes can be reused by containing structures.

Comment: @AdrianMole: `alignas` is a macro wrapping the `_Alignas` keyword, so you're both right. :-)

Comment: @AdrianMole indeed I've run some quick tests and using alignas() / _Alignas does bump up the size of the base struct and the overlay struct by 4 bytes, to make them 16-byte (the size of double on my machine) aligned. BUT it does NOT increase the size of `struct overlay2` which is already double-aligned, of course.  This would suggest the compiler is smart enough to figure it out and not insert those padding alignment bytes when they are not needed for the purposes of alignment.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Hmm. But *you* used the `alignas` **macro** but I didn't. I just used the `_Alignas` keyword. :-)

Comment: ... which, just for laughs, doesn't need any extra header #inlcudes.

Answer (score 1):

Some processors require that pointers to an item of size S must be aligned to the next power-of-two greater than or equal to S, otherwise you get memory alignment faults.

If you take pointer to a variable (including aggregate) that's lesser alignment (lower power-of-two) and cast it to the type of a variable that has higher alignment requirements, you potentially set yourself up for those alignment faults.

If this is likely to be an issue, one option is to put all the item types that will be cast between into a `union`, always allocate that union, and then reference the type within the union.

That has the potential to get expensive on memory, so another possibility is to create a copy function that initialises a greater-alignment object from the contents of the lesser-alignment one, ensuring any additional values the larger one has will be set to sensible default values.

Finally, and since we're talking about linked lists anyway, the better option is to have a single `struct` type that comprises the linked items. It will also contain a `void *` or `union thing *` pointer to the actual data and an indication of what type of data the pointer refers to. This way you're pretty economical with memory, you don't have to worry about alignment issues, and you have the cleanest and most adaptable representation.